# Alert when you've loaded all content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use the following code to scroll to the bottom of a page.

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 1000);
}
```

I need to alert myself when I am done loading all the content, the content is loaded with ajax when I load to the bottom of the page, just like popular social media sites like twitter, facebook, youtube and tumblr do, in this case I am trying to do it with tumblr.

Comment: It's normally the "document ready" event but to make sure all images downloaded you probably need "window onload".

Comment: When I say "loaded" I mean so that you've loaded all the content that page has to offer, not so the tab has actually loaded in the browser.

Comment: ah, I see, then you can do it when the ajax is `done` in your handler for `scroll` event, I guess :)

Comment: That's my question, how do I know when ajax is done.

Comment: @ropuxil: `$.ajax(...).done(function({ alert('done!') })`

Answer (score 1):

To set the alert when your ajax call is done loading, you need to place your code in the ajax callback handler.  If you're doing this with pure javascript then

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   alert('content loaded!');
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
```

If you're doing it with jQuery, then

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_info.txt", 
    success: function(result){
      alert('content loaded!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't own the site, I'm trying to do it on tumblr.com, as I stated in my question.

Comment: This also doesn't verify that there is no more data to be loaded after this 1 class, say they scroll down more.

Comment: Have you checked out the tumblr api? https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2